# Making detail page to dynamically update without reloading the page

Tags: apex, visualforce, related-list, dynamic, detail-page

I am using a visualforce page to create child records of an object.This visualforce page is located on the sidebar of detail page.

Some actions on this visualforce page are creating a record of "Activity" which is a related list on the same object.

What I want is that the record when created gets immediately displayed on the detail page's related list of Activity,without having to refresh the page.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Have you tried to wrap your apex:detail into pageblock (or output panel) and rerender that via actionfunction?

Comment: Hi @Kurunve, actually code from the Apex controller is creating the child record.So, when a button is clicked, record gets created , but we remain on the same detail page,that is standard. To view the recently created record, we have to reload the page everytime.

Comment: oh, it seems I misunderstand your question. In that case, only thing that can be done is reloading of entire page by JS within your visualforce page, but I am afraid SF does not allow that anymore, cause VF and regular view record URL are on different subdomains (parent.location.reload();, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351342/reload-parent-window-from-within-an-iframe)